# Stolen commission?

Tags: management, ethics, company-policy, sales

At my company there is a policy which states that whatever region the deal is signed in, that region gets the deal's commission. I've been watching one of my colleagues working on a deal for months with an international company. Come to signing day, the international company decided to sign the deal in the region of their headquarters (a different region). Even though my colleague did all the hard work, the commission went to someone in a different region. What should I do?

Comment: @Kilisi I don't think there is anything I can do. I could ask the other region to give up their commission, but that is unlikely. My employee is super upset because the commission from this deal is huge. Any way I can handle the situation with my upset employee?

Comment: @Kilisi Thank you for the advice. The region it went to, is a region we work closely with. If I ask the head office, it may seem like I am trying to attack them. I am worried the employee may now not work as hard on deals if the commission doesn't come home. Any way to incentivise them or motivate them. I am almost certain they wont be as motivated to make deals now, knowing the company can just sign in a different region

Comment: @Kilisi If I contact the HO and they take away the commission from the other region, now the other region will feel like I attacked and now will feel that we ripped them off. We have to work with this region a lot

Comment: Is "stolen" accurate here? Nothing in your question says that the other region tried to make this happen. From what you've posted, it sounds like an unfortunate consequence of a poorly-designed policy. That should be addressed, but calling it "stolen" isn't likely to be helpful unless there's very clear evidence that somebody deliberately arranged this situation to get your region's commission.

Comment: "At my company there is a policy which states that whatever region the deal is signed in, that region gets the deal's commission." This is a stupid policy. This tells your employees that if they bring home an account they have *a good chance* at getting a commission.

Comment: "The region it went to, is a region we work closely with. If I ask the head office, it may seem like I am trying to attack them." If the roles were reversed, would you be understanding? Maybe you need to give the people in the other region more credit, and not assume they'll view you as just deciding to attack them, but trying to ensure the situation is fair.

Comment: Did the employee do something to upset the international company in question? If he did, then it would be his fault. In case it's not his fault, can you ask the Home Office to make an exception this one time and pay two commissions? Does your office have a discretionary budget where you could give them some money, or some perk, or a corner office, or something to make up for it. This is a retention issue. If you don't do something, that person will leave and you'll have to replace them at great cost to the company.

Comment: One more question. Did the international company contact a different salesman to negotiate a better deal for themselves? If that's what happened, then your company needs to put measures in place so this doesn't happen again. You don't want salesmen of different regions underbidding each other to get the same business.

Comment: Personally, if I were the home office, I would ask for a copy of all the emails, a log of all the phone calls, and all the contracts, to see how much work was put into this from both sales person. And then of course, I'd speak to both of them as well. Maybe there is a way to split the baby so to speak. And maybe the HO can chip some extra money on top of it.

Comment: Definitely don't use the word 'Stolen' in *any* comms to anyone, it's needlessly inflammatory, and will only serve to annoy people (and make them less likely to see your side of things). Nothing was stolen, there was a misunderstanding.

Comment: What effort did the other region put in to the sale? If the answer is none or almost none, would they really feel entitled to the commission?

Comment: This isn't about fairness, it's about sales commissions, getting them is the primary objective for many, the ways and means are less important. Possession of the commission is 9 tenths of the battle, disputes are usually ignored or rationalised, but no one is giving the money back without a fight just because of fairness.

Answer (score 23):

You need to focus on your responsibilities to your staff member and your region.

Head Office are the only ones who can solve this, so you need to talk to them, outline what you perceive to be the issue and work with them towards a solution.

At this point don't worry about other regions not liking it or anything else of that nature; you have a responsibility to take care of first. Other issues can be looked at later.

Importantly do not try and do anything directly with another region. Head Office needs to be involved to keep things professional if there is any sort of dispute between disparate offices.

In terms of the staff member, inform them that you are doing what you can to resolve it with head office and keep them updated with any progress that you can within the limitations of company policy. For general morale, you not only have to discharge your responsibilities, but in crisis situations (and that's what this is to the employee) you need to be seen doing it.

Personally I'd view this as an issue which if I can resolve in my people's favour will put my credit with them through the roof.

Answer (score 10):

This really should be viewed as an extension of [Kilisi's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171196/stolen-commission/171201#171201).

I just want to speak about policies in general.

Generally speaking, policies are not legally binding. A company can decide to overrule or violate its own policy if it feels like the situation warrants it. (I want to note that a company breaching its own policies can be a factor in certain types of legal situations, but by itself is not legally binding).

So does the company itself have any justification to violating the policy that states "Whatever region the deal is signed in, that region gets the deal's commission"?

I think the answer is yes. It's in the company's best interests to ensure that its sales people are compensated fairly, and to discourage what may become under-handed tactics (even if there were no under-handed tactics here). If your company's best people are losing out on technicalities, they are not going to remain your company's best people. They will become some other company's best people.

In a perfect world, policies would absolutely watertight and account for every eventuality. However we know that it's impossible to plan for every situation that may arise. So there is certain flexibility there.

The best thing that can be done for your employee, and the company as a whole is to ensure HQ is given an understanding of the situation, and is given a chance to "make things right".

In addition, I just want to point out that IF I were a manager of the other region, I certainly would have reached out to HQ to inform them of the situation as well. Maybe this happened and you are not aware.